# Grails: IE Tabbing Issues

Tags: internet-explorer

I have asked a question very similar to this in the past but the answer did fix the problem.  In a page I am making, there are modal boxes that are rendered after the page has been rendered.  In Chrome and Firefox, the tabbing on these newly generated modal forms works just fine.  In IE however, all hell breaks loose and I really have no control.  I have tried things like setting tab order but to no avail.  Has anyone else had this problem and does anyone know the fix for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I found answer a while ago and am just now getting to report what the problem was.  The modal framework [modalbox.js] I was using was what caused the problems.